# How to get bin folder in ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

With asp.net core 1.0 There are lots of functionality added. But there is not way to get Bin Folder path.

Can anyone please know how we can get the bin folder path for asp.net core 1.0 application.

Comment: Why do you want a bin folder?

Comment: @MuqeetKhan One reason would be to retrieve the produced XML documentation file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, the bin folder does exists but it is moved to **artifacts folder** next to the solution file. Since ASP.NET Core RC 1 compiles everything in memory, you will find empty bin folder. But if you set "Produce output on build" option to true (Right click Project file -> Properties and Build tab) then you will find the generated files in bin folder.

I don't think so there is any direct property available as to get the path of this  but you can use the same solution pointed out by @Nikolay Kostov to get application path. And then using System.IO classes jump to bin folder.

**Code updated to for ASP.NET Core as mentioned here.**

http://www.talkingdotnet.com/get-application-wwwroot-path-aspnet-core-rc2/

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appenv)
{
     string sAppPath = env.ContentRootPath;
     string sRootPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(sAppPath, @"..\..\"));
     string sBinFolderPath = @"artifacts\bin\" + appenv.ApplicationName;
     string sBinPath = Path.Combine(sRootPath, sBinFolderPath);
}
```

Answer (score 38):

Alternative way (corresponds to the AppDomain.BaseDirectory):

```
AppContext.BaseDirectory
```

Answer (score 31):

This works to retrieve the assembly's directory, from which we can determine the `bin` location.

```
var location = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
var directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(location);
System.Console.WriteLine(directory);
```

Output

```
C:\MyApplication\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0
```

Comment: Works for me on my local environment, but can it work on Azure API Service?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really get the `/bin/` folder since it is not relevant to your project and the ASP.NET environment doesn't know what a `/bin/` folder is.

And also there isn't exactly a `/bin/` folder. You may want to read this article: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/understanding-aspnet5-apps.html

But you can get the so called `ApplicationBasePath` which is the directory in which you application runs:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{
     string baseDir = appEnv.ApplicationBasePath;
     // Other startup code
}
```

Comment: It is giving the folder with src which I don't want

Comment: Well there isn't exactly a `/bin/` folder. You may want to read this article: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/understanding-aspnet5-apps.html so the project root is the place where the code is started

Comment: @JalpeshVadgama: This means you're running in the IDE.

Comment: The `src` folder is for published client script source. Where do you think ASP.NET put's the DLL your project compiles to? If you copy something to output during build, like a SQL script, it is copied to a `bin` folder, and to use that SQL script, you need to know the full disk path to wherever that script file is.

Comment: Ancient history now but IApplicationEnvironment has been removed.  https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/171

Answer (score 0):

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;