# Load Unmanaged dll reference in ASP.NET MVC Core 1.0 (Aka) ASP.net 5 MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, naudio, asp.net5

This question relates to an ASP.NET MVC WEP API, and Naudio

***what I want***

I was working prototype in WPF appliations when I use this code the wav file is converted to mp3

```cs
var retMs = new MemoryStream();
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("sound.wav")))
using (var rdr = new WaveFileReader(ms))
using (var wtr = new LameMP3FileWriter(retMs, rdr.WaveFormat, 128))
{
    rdr.CopyTo(wtr);
}
return retMs.ToArray();
```

But when using this code in api project I am getting error like this

> Unable to load DLL 'libmp3lame.dll': The specified module could not be
> found.

I know ***libmp3lame*** is unmanged dll, the WPF project I just copy  the dll to bin folder and everything works fine, but how can I achieve this in Web API project, I mean asp.net 5 project

***Note***
*the above code is working expected in wpf project*

Also now I am only supported in my API is dotnetframwork **means windows only**
*I removed other platform dependencies*

**Update:**

Created Issue in ASP.Net MVC [Repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4601)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party but I'll share this for posterity.  NAudio can convert a WAVE to an MP3 without the unmanaged DLL to avoid this issue all together.  The only snag is it has to write out to a file (which can then be read back in).  Assuming you have a MemoryStream where you read all the bytes in (like you did):

```
using (var wfr = new WaveFileReader(ms))
{
    MediaFoundationApi.Startup();
    MediaFoundationEncoder.EncodeToMp3(wfr, @"C:\Temp\test.mp3", 48000);
    MediaFoundationApi.Shutdown();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like an issue with getting the mapping to the module in the bin library path, check out the following as may help -

[How to get bin folder in ASP.NET Core 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527144/how-to-get-bin-folder-in-asp-net-core-1-0)

[MVC4 App "Unable to load DLL 'libmp3lame.32.dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088743/mvc4-app-unable-to-load-dll-libmp3lame-32-dll)