# How to access files outputed by copyToOutput?

Tags: .net-core

I´m trying to output a xml file that I have in my .net core api project and then accessing that file later on in the code.

I have this code in my project.json to output the xml

```
"buildOptions": {
"emitEntryPoint": true,
    "copyToOutput":  "myfile.xml"
"preserveCompilationContext": true
}
```

And then I try to access it like this

```
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var path = env.ContentRootPath;
        var filepath = Path.Combine(path, "myfile.xml");
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(fileName); //throws error
    }
```

But when I run this in Azure I get this error

> FileNotFoundException - Could not find file
>   'D:\home\site\wwwroot\myfile.xml'.

I have tried every version of e.g [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35598771/1187583) but with no luck.

**UPDATE 1**

Here is my Main method in Program.cs

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
.UseKestrel()
.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.UseIISIntegration()
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.Build();
```

I tried to find the xml file by browsing (with Kudu Service) every thinkable folder so I´m thinking that the xml file doesn´t get build out
https://myvsts.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/

**UPDATE 2**

I found out that copyToOutput works just fine locally but not on azure. I implemented [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers) to browse the folder and my xml file does not show up **until** I right click it and press publish! Its like the project publish doesn´t pick it up...

Answer (score 0):

It appears your ContentRootPath is set to the wwwroot folder. Normally, this is is set to the folder that *contains* wwwroot and `IHostingEnvironment.WebRootPath` points to the "wwwroot" path.

Check that your Program.Main class has this:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
   .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
```

Also, you may need to also add this file to "publishOptions". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#publishoptions

```
"publishOptions": {
  "include": ["myfile.xml"]
}
```

Comment: I´m not quite following you :-) I updated my question. Could it be that the xml is not buiding out?

Comment: Ok I spotted "contains", I misser that. But regardless I can't find the file while browsing. I also tried to add the file to another class library and set it to copyIfNewer but still can't find the file...

Comment: Hmm. I added one more suggestion, although it appears from updates that you figured it out.